# Visual Studio IDE: go to previous match in multi caret/cursor

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Consider the following setup:

I have:

```
Test 1

T|est 2

Test 3
```

where `|` is the current cursor position. Application of <kbd>Shft</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> first highlights `Test` of `Test 2`. Subsequent application of <kbd>Shft</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> takes one to `Test` of `Test 3`. Is there a way to reverse this direction of movement and go from `Test` of `Test 2` to `Test` of `Test 1`?

The command `Edit.InsertNextMatchingCaret` is default mapped to <kbd>Shft</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> There does not seem to be a command `Edit.InsertPreviousMatchingCaret`.

See gif below for visual description of the issue:

[image]

Comment: Can you tag the specific version of Visual Studio that you are using as [visual-studio] could include VS 2008.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, AFAIK, there's no out-of-the-box way to achieve this using keyboard shortcuts. Moving the caret works only in one direction in muti-caret editing. To select the previous match, you may use one of two options:

- **Option 1:** Select the match manually using keyboard and mouse:

  Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> and then use the mouse to manually select the previous match (e.g., double click on the "Test" word in the "Test 1" line).
- **Option 2:** If you want to rely on hotkeys only, you may use the following workaround:

  1. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> to select the next match.
  2. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> to move the caret/selection to the following match.
  3. Repeat step #2 until you get to to the desired match.

  Here's a demo:

  [image]

Comment: Thanks for the workarounds. I was really looking for keyboard shortcuts. In C++ and other languages, I am sure, it is important when you are on a word/variable, to know how far above it is defined and where / how it is changed prior to the cursor location within the current scope. The 2nd option you suggest would not help for this case since the variable one reaches after wrap around could be in a totally different scope. :-( VSCode has a keyboard shortcut for this, but it is surprising VSIDE does not !